# Enthalpy Changes

Tags: thermodynamics, enthalpy

0.50 g of Mg is added to a 50 mL HCl solution. The temperature increased by 5.2 degree Celsius. Calculate the enthalpy change for the reaction per mole of Mg that reacted.

Comment: What is the concentration of the HCl solution? Did all the Mg react?

Answer (score 1):

We assume all the Mg reacts, which means that $\frac{1}{48}$ mol of Mg reacts with 50 ml

The enthalpy change for $\frac{1}{48}$ mol is given by $\Delta H = mC\Delta T = 50 \times 4.186 \times 5.2 \space J$

Therefore, the enthalpy change per mole is $48 \times \Delta H = 52.241 \space kJ \space mol^{-1}$